# Android RemoveViewAt not removing each view

Tags: android, view

Each time the player moves in my game I am attempting to iterate through my RelativeLayout and remove all views (except for my map - which handles all clicks).  I found when I use **gameActivityRelativeLayout.removeAllViews();** it will mess with the ontouchevent code.  I loop through each child view and remove them all yet somehow they don't all get removed.  I have searched extensively and tried many ways, but am unable to figure this out.

```
if (GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout != null) {
    activity_game.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //remove all views except for mapImageView
            for (int i = 0; i < GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                View tmpView = GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if (!(tmpView instanceof MapImageView)){ //remove all views other than mapImageView
                    GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.removeViewAt(i);
                }
            }

            Log.i("jay", "====Below view should only be mapImageView1====");
            for (int i = 0; i < GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                View tmpView = GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
                Log.i("jay", "View: " + tmpView + "tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): " + tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID));
            }
            Log.i("jay", "====Above view should only be mapImageView1====");

            //removing all and then readding mapImageView screwed up the ontouchevent code
            //GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.removeAllViews();
            //GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.addView(GameActivity.mapImageView);

            //add all of the mob/npcs/enemy players/tradeskills/etc. to the screen
            for (ImageView temp : MapImageView.tmpImageViewPool) {
                if (temp.getParent() != GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout){
                    temp.invalidate();
                    GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.addView(temp);
                }
            }

            GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.invalidate();
            GameActivity.mapImageView.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my log file showing that the children are really not all removed like they should be.

```
I/jay: ====Below view should only be mapImageView1====
I/jay: View: com.kisnardonline.graphics.MapImageView{7f37236 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1440,2392} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): mapImageView
I/jay: View: android.widget.ImageView{aab4871 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-112,112} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): res/images/object/object_gothic_window.png:  1112,1140
I/jay: View: android.widget.ImageView{3667656 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-112,112} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): res/images/object/object_gothic_window.png:  888,1476
I/jay: View: android.widget.ImageView{732c6d7 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-112,112} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): res/images/npc/npc_dev_arm.png:  888,916
I/jay: View: android.widget.ImageView{a7e5bc4 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-112,112} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): res/images/npc/npc_dev_itm.png:  776,1364
I/jay: View: android.widget.ImageView{55afaad V.ED..... ........ 0,0-45,45} tmpView.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID): null
I/jay: ====Above view should only be mapImageView1====
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the child position is not unique when we start deleting like this. Once you delete view at position 0. The view at position 1 becomes position 0. So one way to do this

```
int count = GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildCount();

    while(count>1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    View tmpView = GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if (!(tmpView instanceof MapImageView)) { //remove all views other than mapImageView
    GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.removeViewAt(i);
                                            }            
}
    count = GameActivity.gameActivityRelativeLayout.getChildCount();
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much.  Did not know it removed in such a fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want iterate childs to delete some of them by some feature (for example, all ImageViews or views with some tag) - do iteration backwards:

```
for (int i = someParentLayout.getChildCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        View v = someParentLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            someParentLayout.removeViewAt(i);
        }
    }
```

in this case count of childs will be decreasing after every iteration but it doesn't affect you